# How to randomly spawn a Rect on x position (android studio)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to draw a rect with a 50x50 size, however I want it to appear randomly on the x position. Where should i set the x position?

This is how i set my rectangle.

```
rectangle.set(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

I've done several changes on this setting the but I can't figure it out.

Comment: generate a random number, assign that number to x and pass x to `rectange.set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
rectangle.set(randomX, 50, randomX + 50, 100);
```

Where `randomX` is the random value.